# Adding checks in clients is mandatory in sensu ? Can't we add checks in only server and monitor the clients?

Tags: sensu

I have added some checks in the sensu server and also subscribed for those checks, But the checks are not being seen in the UI for clients. Is it mandatory to add the checks in clients?

Comment: I guess you get 'check not found' for your checks on the clients? I also tried to add a client today and got the same.

Comment: I didn't get any such error, But the checks are not there in Client.

Comment: Then what is the problem? I don't get it. Explain better.

Comment: Is the check code deployed to the client machine?

Answer (score 0):

It is the normal thing to do. This is because the client, at the end, will only execute the "command" you specified for the particular check. This also implies that the command must be visible, i.e. in $PATH when "sensu" user tries to execute it (by default sensu adds /etc/sensu/plugins to $PATH).

I guess you could, in theory, reach the plugin from the clients accessing a mounted location pointing to the server, something like command='/net//path/to/script.sh -arguments'.

However, if you manage your infrastructure with something like [Chef](https://www.chef.io/) (you should, it's awesome) it should be easy to deploy the check scripts into the clients.